# Decoding a preg_match

Tags: preg-match

I'm trying to figure out what the password requirements are for a custom CMS i'm using. I found the piece of code that checks the passwords. From what I can see are these the correct requirements? 
**7 - 20 Characters, aZ and 0-9 characters acceptable.**

```
if (!preg_match("/^.*(?=.{7,20})(((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]))|((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]))).*$/",$password)) {
```

Comment: Head on over to https://regex101.com It will explain the regex to you and allow you to try it out with various values.

Comment: @CollinD thanks, that answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend heading over to https://regex101.com . It has an automated tool that will parse out regex into (somewhat readable) english, and let you test candidates right in the browser.